# What happens to a 2019 UA Artificer's Infused Bag of Holding when it de-infuses?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, artificer

With the [new 2019 UA Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf), once per long rest you can 'create' a magical item if you know its infusion. This has a set limit based on level, but once you reach that limit any additional magic items you infuse will negate the last-most item you've created.

If my Artificer fills a bag of holding with TNT, cycles through his other infusions, and then infuses an item mid-combat, will his now defunct Bag of Holding drop its payload for extreme success?

Comment: "my Artificer fills a bag of holding with TNT" where did they get so much TNT ?

Comment: How would your artificer infuse an item mid-combat? Are they going to ask the enemies nicely to wait 8 hours for them to take a long rest?

Comment: @RyanThompson It's a touch-action and it would be something done before hand. Infusions are indefinite, up until either the Artificer's death or if a new item is infused. You would coordinate it before hand before combat, ideally.

Comment: @SKC You can only infuse at the end of a long rest. You aren't going to be able to complete a long rest mid-combat, so you can't infuse mid-combat. (Also, it's not limited to one infusion per long rest.)

Answer (score 8):

Remember the typical disclaimer about playtest material. I don't think the designers considered that scenario yet.  There are two options within the description of [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) that  it could lead to.

### Bag is Destroyed

The first is considering the bag "destroyed", which seems the most likely outcome RAW:

> If the bag is overloaded, pierced, or torn, it ruptures and is destroyed, and its contents are scattered in the Astral Plane.

### Bag is turned out

The other option is consider it to be turned inside out:

> If the bag is turned inside out, its contents spill forth, unharmed, but the bag must be put right before it can be used again.

Which is much more generous to the player, and in line with the [Artificer's Infusion of Many Pockets](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf):

> If this infusion ends, the items stored in the shared space move into one of the pouches, determined at random. The rest of the pouches become empty.

### [W]ill his now defunct Bag of Holding drop its payload for extreme success?

Neither of these options would set off the TNT.  One them takes the TNT and dumps it into the astral plane. The other dumps the TNT, unlight, on the floor.

Also, keep in mind you can only infuse after just finishing a long rest, so doing so in battle is typically impossible or at least very unwise -- unless you were ambushed at the end of a long rest:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a   magic item.

Comment: With the class officially released, is there a change in this answer?

Comment: The infusion didn't change as far text is concerned.  So, I believe this still accurate.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that much. Thanks. By the way, should you need to update the answer since it is not longer play-test material or a new question should be asked?

Comment: I don't know.  That's likely a question someone has already asked in Meta about when UA becomes official.  I imagine it should be a new question, because it could have changed -- it just didn't in this case.

Comment: One of my players asked me this just now. I disagree that a bag rupture is the most RAW result; the whole reason this is happening is that the bag is no longer a Bag of Holding, so how can it rupture and invoke an effect specific to a Bag of Holding?