# Can my artificer use an Infusion to create a Bag of Holding everyday for profit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, artificer, artificer-infusions

Can my artificer make a bag of holding everyday and then sell them for gold? And yes I have the infusion for this.

Answer (score 12):

## You can only have one *bag of holding* active at once

In *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, p. 57, under the Artificer class description, the section Infuse Item says:

> #### Infusing an Item
>
> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item. [...]
>
> Your infusion remains in an item indefinitely [...]
>
> You can infuse more than one nonmagical object at the end of a long rest; the maximum number of objects appears in the Infused Items column of the Artificer table. You must touch each of the objects, and **each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time**. [...] If you try to exceed your maximum number of infusions, the oldest infusion immediately ends, and then the new infusion applies.

It makes it clear that you cannot use the same infusion on one object, so you could, at most, make one *bag of holding* at a time, and if you created another one, the first one would cease to be a *bag of holding*.

If you skipped town after selling one before you made a new one (thereby making the one you sold become a mundane bag again), you could in theory make a profit, but your reputation could soon catch up with you...

Comment: Now I really want to know what happens if a very full Bag Of Holding suddenly becomes mundane

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah, that bad reputation could get a lot worse depending on what and how much was put in there first... might be worth asking a separate question about?

Comment: @Medix2 I'm like 85% certain that everything that won't fit inside spills out around it. Which, if it's filled with, say, an inhaled poison that makes you forget stuff...

Comment: @Medix2: A corresponding question about the 2019 UA version of the artificer: [What happens to a 2019 UA Artificer's Infused Bag of Holding when it de-infuses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/149408/33569)